# How can I add a type hint for a number coming from some unknown numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-typing

I'm making a library that contains some methods whose parameters include numbers that may come from numpy arrays. E.g., one of my methods is roughly `some_func(my_array, my_array[0, 0])`, where the second param is a number of an unknown type (it could be a `np.float64`, some numpy integer type, whatever). Also, it could be a builtin python number type like `float`. I want to add a type hint that handles this case, i.e. declare the method with `def some_func(array: np.ndarray, value: Foo)`, but I'm not sure what to put for `Foo`. Does anyone have any good ideas? Is there an established pattern here?

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that appears to be in use by numpy themselves is to just call them `float` and `int`.

Here is the definition for [`numpy.Array.__add__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d2f60fff5f7ec4ba379bba858f8ad91f55118305/numpy/array_api/_array_object.py#L432C2-L432C2) and it looks like this:

```
    def __add__(self: Array, other: Union[int, float, Array], /) -> Array:
```

And here is the definition for [`arange`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d2f60fff5f7ec4ba379bba858f8ad91f55118305/numpy/array_api/_creation_functions.py#L75C1-L75C1) and it looks like this with the same type hinting decision:

```
def arange(
    start: Union[int, float],
    /,
    stop: Optional[Union[int, float]] = None,
    step: Union[int, float] = 1,
    *,
    dtype: Optional[Dtype] = None,
    device: Optional[Device] = None,
) -> Array:
```